# Джава сервлеты , получение данных от другой программы на джава

Tags: java, servlet

Сам сервлет

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //  сюда нужен код для получения данных от другой джава программы
        //  ????????????????????????????? 
    }
}
```

Другая программа отправляющаая данные сервлету

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("http://localhost:8080/hello").openConnection();

            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write("111111".getBytes());
            outputStream.write("111111".getBytes());
            outputStream.write("111111".getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вопрос какой код нужно вставить на месте комментария в сервлете

Answer (score 2):

```
try (InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()))) {
    int c;
    while((с = in.read()) != -1) {
        // Что-нибудь делаете с принятым символом
    }
}
```